# map() function not working as intended with firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Alright, so basically I was trying to create a basic chat application, where I'm storing users and their chats in firestore and I was mapping through the chat.

Here is my file.

```
const Sidebar = () => {
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
    const userChatRef = db.collection('chats').where('users', 'array-contains', user.email);
    const [chatSnapshot] = useCollection(userChatRef);

    const createChat = () => {
        const input = prompt('Enter an Email address: ');
        if (!input) return null;
        if (EmailValidator.validate(input) && !chatExist(input) && input !== user.email) {
            db.collection("chats").add({
                users: [user.email, input],
            })
        }
    }

    // checking if chat already exists or not
    const chatExist = (recipientEmail) =>
        !!chatSnapshot?.docs.find(
            (chat) => chat.data().users.find((user) => user === recipientEmail)?.length > 0
        );

    return (
        <Container>
                {chatSnapshot?.docs.map((chat) => (
                    <UserChat key={chat.id} id={chat.id} user={chat.data().users} />
                ))}
        </Container>
    )
};

export default Sidebar;
```

And here is my firestore db, look it's not empty but still mapping is not working.

[image: My firestore]

I'm somewhat a beginner with firestore so please let me know what I'm doing wrong, helps would be appreciated :)

Comment: The query looks fine at first glance. Did you already try loading it through `get` and logging the results, to see if the problem is on the database side or on the side of rendering the results in react?

Comment: Could you please tell what behavior you're expecting from the `map()` function? As @FrankvanPuffelen said, the query looks good. What are the results you’re getting when you use it now?

Comment: Thanks for the help but I fixed this issue. Thanks. Idk what was the issue I just restarted the server and just did some changes before and it got fixed.

Comment: @GouravSinghRawat Would you mind to post the steps you did as a formal answer to help other users that have a similar problem.